# Android timer doesn't go below ~120ms resolution

Tags: java, android, timer

I've been trying to send my Android phone's sensor data to my PC via a TCP Socket connection. I'm aiming for a ~10-40ms refresh rate, I'm doing research on the potential applications of phone sensors for measurement technology which involves placing the phone on a swing, and measuring the acceleration using the phone's sensor.

Here comes my problem: however I try to time sending the messages via the Socket, I can't go below a refresh rate of about 120ms. If I set no delay at all, using a simple `while(true)` loop, it goes blazing fast (as expected), but when I try to implement a delay of any kind (from 1ms to 100ms, doesn't matter), the delay just doesn't go below ~120ms.

Here are some examples of what I've tried so far:

```
//outside of onCreate()
final long refreshRate=10;//millisecods
long time;

//in onCreate()
//...
time=System.currentTimeMillis();//initial setup
//...
dataBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!isSendingData){
                isSendingData=true;
                dataBtn.setText("Stop sending data");

                new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        while(isConnected&&isSendingData&&mTcpClient!=null){//TODO
                            long currentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                            if(currentTime-time>=refreshRate){
                                String sx=String.format(Locale.GERMANY,"%3.2f", x);
                                String sy=String.format(Locale.GERMANY,"%3.2f", y);
                                String sz=String.format(Locale.GERMANY,"%3.2f", z);
                                try{
                                    mTcpClient.sendMessage(sx+";"+sy+";"+sz+";");//TODO trycatch testing
                                }catch(Exception e){
                                    isSendingData=false;
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                time=currentTime;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.start();

            }else{
                isSendingData=false;
                dataBtn.setText("Start sending data");
            }
        }
    });
```

Other example:

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
                myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        while(isConnected&&isSendingData&&mTcpClient!=null){

                                String sx=String.format(Locale.GERMANY,"%3.2f", x);
                                String sy=String.format(Locale.GERMANY,"%3.2f", y);
                                String sz=String.format(Locale.GERMANY,"%3.2f", z);
                                try{
                                    mTcpClient.sendMessage(sx+";"+sy+";"+sz+";");//TODO trycatch testing
                                }catch(Exception e){
                                    isSendingData=false;
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }


                        }
                        if(!isSendingData||!isConnected||mTcpClient==null)this.cancel();
                    }
                }, 10, 10);
```

Comment: Are any of the clocks in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html better?

Answer (score 0):

Sending timing messages via a socket is a horrible idea.  YOu're dependent on network latency, lag spikes, network congestion, and the OSes internal delays.  Just don't do that.  There is no way to ever make that a stable, working technology.  Especially via TCP, which must recieve all bytes in order and resend if missing.  A single missed packet woul cause all further updates to wait for that packet to be resent.  UDP would fit better but even that is a horrible idea.

The correct way to do this is purely local, using a local timer.